# При вводе новых данных в мини-органайзер, выводится ошибка и не появляются новые данные в таблице

Tags: java, javafx

Делал небольшой органайзер в стиле записника **TODO**, но столкнулся с проблемой: при вводе новой информации в текстовое поле и нажатие на кнопку "*ОК*" (именно после этого) выводится ошибка, расшифровать её не могу, т.к. ещё и Junior'ом себя назвать не могу. **JavaFX - Первый день**, так сказать. Прикладываю все (жуть) файлы к сообщению.

**Main.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import sample.model.CollectionTaskList;
import sample.model.Task;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Button addTaskBtn;
    @FXML
    TextField newTaskField;
    @FXML
    TableView tableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn tableColumn;
    CollectionTaskList taskList;

    public Controller(){
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }
    public void initialize(){
        taskList = new CollectionTaskList();
        tableView.setItems(taskList.getTaskList());
        tableColumn.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("text"));
    }

    public void addTask(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        String tasktext = newTaskField.getText();
        taskList.addTask(new Task(tasktext));
    }
}
```

**Task.java**

```
package sample.model;

public class Task {
    String text;
    boolean isDone;
    public Task(String text){
        this.text = text;
        isDone = false;
    }
}
```

**TaskList.java** - интерфейс

```
package sample.model.interfaces;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import sample.model.Task;

public interface TaskList {
    public ObservableList<Task> getTaskList();
    public void addTask(Task task);
    public void removeTask(Task task);
}
```

**CollectionTaskList.java**

```
package sample.model;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import sample.model.interfaces.TaskList;

public class CollectionTaskList implements TaskList {
    ObservableList<Task> tasks;
    public CollectionTaskList(){
        tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Task> getTaskList() {
        return tasks;
    }

    @Override
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTask(Task task) {
        tasks.remove(task);
    }
}
```

Ну и самое интересное, конечно же, fxml-файл. По-классике, **sample.fxml**.
Вот ссылка: http://snippi.com/s/vsezeps - документ мой и сделаный ручками (ну почти ручками, скорее в SceneBuilder).

Ошибка, выдаваемая консолью, при нажатии кнопки:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.controls@10.0.2/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.controls@10.0.2/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.createCell(TableRowSkin.java:213)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.createCell(TableRowSkin.java:62)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.createCellAndCache(TableRowSkinBase.java:740)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.recreateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:734)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.(TableRowSkinBase.java:158)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.(TableRowSkin.java:89)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
>       at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:147)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9515)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9602)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1715)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1692)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1801)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2638)
>       at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1218)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1218)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1218)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:590)
>       at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2507)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:410)
>       at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:409)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:436)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Comment: текст ошибки бы тоже приложить

Comment: @zolt Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.controls@10.0.2/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.controls@10.0.2/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
 at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)

(...)

at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Comment: @zolt я правил основное сообщение

Comment: В таблице только одна колонка?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim Да.

Comment: Попробуй поменять setCellFactory на setCellValueFactory

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim стало лучше, автоматически появились строчки, вот выдает теперь:

javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory getCellDataReflectively
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'text' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@76e414a6 with provided class type: class sample.model.Task
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read from unreadable property text

Comment: Добавь в Task сеттеры и геттеры для полей. Если ты в Idea пишешь проект, там в контекстном меню есть Generate, где сможешь все нужное сделать автоматически.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю **Riĥard Brugekĥaim** и **zolt** за подсказки. Решение проблемы заключается в следующих двух моментах:

- `tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("text"));` вместо обычного `setCellFactory`.
- Нужен **геттер** с возвратом текста в эти же колонки.

  ```
  public String getText(){
      return text;
  }
  ```

Comment: @Riĥard Brugekĥaim Теперь вопрос в другом, как сделать функцию удаления строки, содержание которой такое, как указано в textField? Я понимаю, что там где-то equals нужен, но как именно писать код - без понятия.

Comment: А это уже нужно ручками писать. Прописывать событие в textField на изменение содержимого и в этом событии перебирать содержимое таблицы.